# Microsoft teams adaptive card choice set doesn't clear error

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have developed a Microsoft Teams app and i use adaptive cards. In the message i sent i have used adaptive card's choice set. When no option is picked from the choice set the submit fails correctly with error message. But now after selecting an option from the choice set the error message doesn't go away and the submit also doesn't work. This problem doesn't exist in Teams mobile client and adaptive card designer but only in desktop and web. Is there a workaround for my payload. Here’s the payload....

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.4",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "verticalContentAlignment": "Top",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "You have a new notification:\n\n*[ testing 123 : Approval ](https://app.example.com)*",
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "type": "FactSet",
          "facts": [
            {
              "title": "Requester",
              "value": "[teams-app review](mailto:abc@example.com)"
            },
            {
              "title": "Title",
              "value": "testing 123"
            },
            {
              "title": "Supplier",
              "value": "MARK10"
            },
            {
              "title": "Region",
              "value": "United States"
            },
            {
              "title": "Business entity",
              "value": "Teams-testing"
            },
            {
              "title": "Summary",
              "value": "qwerty hi"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "ActionSet",
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "Action.ShowCard",
              "title": "Request more info",
              "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                  {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    "choices": [
                      {
                        "title": "teams-app review (Requester)",
                        "value": "{\"name\":\"teams-app review\",\"userName\":\"teams-app-review\",\"department\":\"Requester\"}"
                      }
                    ],
                    "placeholder": "choose one ore more participants",
                    "id": "rmi.participant",
                    "isMultiSelect": true,
                    "wrap": true,
                    "isRequired": true,
                    "errorMessage": "Please choose one or more participants",
                    "label": "From"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "placeholder": "enter your request here...",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "maxLength": 250,
                    "isRequired": true,
                    "label": "Request",
                    "id": "rmi.request",
                    "errorMessage": "Please enter your request"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "Submit",
                        "id": "RMI.Submit",
                        "data": {
                          "processContext": {
                            "taskId": "336507284123746331",
                            "discussionId": null,
                            "emailId": "admin@M365x90692327.onmicrosoft.com",
                            "username": "teams-app-review",
                            "name": "teams-app review",
                            "tenantId": "teams_testing",
                            "engagementId": "336507052528379775"
                          },
                          "triggerActionType": "TASK_REQUEST_MORE_INFO"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "id": "RMI_ACTION"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "bleed": true,
      "spacing": "Small"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since it works in adaptive card designer and teams mobile client, i was expecting it to work in teams desktop and web client as well.

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue. The card action does work in mobile client. However, it is not working in Desktop/Web client.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: We have discussed this with engineering team and according to them it is expected to behave this way currently. They suggested to NOT use commas in choice values, for now. In future they will incorporate this suggestion and will make necessary changes. Thanks!

Comment: In my example above, value is a string. Also this seems to work fine on mobile and in the adaptive card designer. Please can you fix the bug?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT please can you comment? It will be good to get this fixed.

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will update you accordingly.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT any updates on this issue?

Comment: We got update from engineering team that, current adaptive card documentation at [Schema Explorer | Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Choice.html) notes that the raw value for Input.Choice can't contain commas which is the problem with the provided payload (using a JSON string literal as a value). 

The difference in behavior occurs because Mobile is not handling the validation in the same way (allowing values with commas), but it shouldn't matter because users should not be using values with commas anyway.